# Closing InputStream hangs when reading a radio stream

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using Apache HttpClient to fetch meta-data from radio stream. What I want to do is make a GET request, read some bytes then close the stream. For some streams, it works properly but for some others, the closing of the stream hangs. It looks like it's still receiving data and not closing the connection while it's happening.

```java
    public SongInfo retrieveMetadata(String streamUrl) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(streamUrl);
        httpGet.addHeader("Icy-MetaData", "1");
        httpGet.addHeader("Connection", "close");
        httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "");
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("An exception occurred while fetching the stream", e);
            return null;
        }

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            log.warn("Could not fetch stream. Status line: "+ response.getStatusLine());
            return null;
        }

        int metadataOffset = retrieveMetadataOffset(response);

        if (metadataOffset == 0) {
            log.info("Could not find metadata for url:"+ streamUrl);
            return null;
        }

        List<Metadata> metadata = extractMetadata(response, metadataOffset);
        if (metadata == null || metadata.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return extractSongInfo(metadata);
    }
    private List<Metadata> extractMetadata(HttpResponse response, int metadataOffset) {
        String metadataStr;
        try(InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent()) {
            if (stream.skip(metadataOffset) != metadataOffset) {
                log.warn("Something went wrong while skipping to metadata offset");
                return null;
            }
            int metaDataLength = stream.read() * 16;
            metadataStr = getMetadataStr(stream, metaDataLength);
            if (metadataStr == null) {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("Something went wrong while reading the stream", e);
            return null;
        } //Hangs here
        //rest of the method
    }
```

I noticed that the stream returned by `response.getEntity().getContent()` is of type `EofSensorInputStream` so I'm wondering if it's waiting for a EOF character which is never coming.

Example of stream for which the code works properly and the stream closes properly: https://icecast.omroep.nl/radio2-bb-mp3, http://live-mp3-128.kexp.org
Example of stream for which the code doesn't work properly as the stream never closes and hangs forever: https://kexp-mp3-128.streamguys1.com/kexp128.mp3

Comment: An `EofSensorInputStream` does special stuff when it is closed.  I would suggest that you step into the `close` call in your debugger and try to figure out what's going on by seeing just where it is hanging.  If you haven't already done so, I would suggest that you look closely at the logic of how many bytes are skipped and how many bytes are read.  Maybe there's a pattern there as to when the request succeeds and when it hangs.

Comment: I can see it's still actively processing data because `org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0` logs like crazy

Comment: What are the log entries saying?

Comment: `18:50:51.101 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0xff][0xfb][0x92]`][0x80][0x2][0xf5][0x19][0xca][0xeb]lA[0xd0]4[0xed][0x88]p[0x8][0x2][0xe0]O[0x8][0xff]'.0[0xcb]@[0xaa][0x80]"[0xf0][0x10][0x89][0xb8]"[0xe7]4p\[0xb0][0x9e]7[0xa1][0xf5][0x8b][0x84][0xc5][0xcf][0xcc]C[0xe1]o[0xa0]:.%[0x0][0xdc][0xff][0xa4][0xca]f[0xe8]?f[0xf5][0xd2]/[0xff][0xbd][0xa5];[0xa7][0xff]w[0xe7][0xcd][0xba][0x9e][0xfd][0xfb]fB[0x10]!I[0x90]Uv[0x9b]b[0x8f][0xb6][0x94]Sd[0xce][0xc1]r[0xb][0x83][0xc1][0x95][0xbc]2d?[0x9c][0x14]9[0x9f][0xff][0xe9][0x97][0xa8][0x0]@u[0x4][0x89][0x1][\n]"`

Comment: As a side note: Your `stream.skip` call is rather brittle; [`InputStream.skip(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#skip(long)) can "for a variety of reasons" skip less bytes than requested despite not having reached the end of the stream. In case you are using Java 12 or higher it would be better to use [`InputStream.skipNBytes(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#skipNBytes(long)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because calling `close()` on the content stream will try to consume the remaining content. This is currently not explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent()) (see also [HTTPCORE-656](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCORE-656)), but is mentioned in the [tutorials](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e145):

> The difference between closing the content stream and closing the response is that the former will attempt to keep the underlying connection alive by consuming the entity content while the latter immediately shuts down and discards the connection.
> [...]
> There can be situations, however, when only a small portion of the entire response content needs to be retrieved and the performance penalty for consuming the remaining content and making the connection reusable is too high, in which case one can terminate the content stream by closing the response.

Therefore in your case it seems appropriate to **not** close the `InputStream` returned by `getContent()` but only close the `HttpResponse` (which you are apparently not doing yet).

Comment: Indeed, this does the trick, thanks a lot. Out of curiosity, do you have an idea why this didn't happen for all streams?

Comment: @Migwel, I am not completely sure, but it appears `IdentityInputStream` (which is used for the other HTTP connections to the URLs you provided) does not implement `close()` as described in its documentation (see [HTTPCORE-655](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCORE-655)); it apparently does not try to consume the remaining content.